# how to control responsive template with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design

I made a two pages of my index page One is normal page (none responsive) and second one responsive view for mobile, Tablet. Now i want to display second one page when media screen less then 1000. i wrote that jquery script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (window.screen.width < 1000){
document.location = "mobile-resposive.html";
}
//-->
</script>
```

but its couldn't work. What i have to do that. Please let me know what I'm missing? I want to display this page for every tablet and mobile.

Comment: suppose you are changes `.html` page, but this can be wrong when window `resize` call event on window resize event.. although I don't think this is responsive control.. use `CSS` @media query with same `HTML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirement I will prefer to use **media queries** but if you want to use Jquery then :

Try `$(window).width()` as shown :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
   if ($(window).width() < 1000){
     document.location = "mobile-resposive.html";
   }
 });
</script>
```

[**Difference between `window.screen.width` and `$(window).width()` is here(click here).**](http://jsfiddle.net/av7gezmt/)

**NOTE :-** Just a suggestion always try to use **window.location** instead of **document.location**.

Comment: @Kartikeya yeah it's work now ... Thank you soo much sorry for the late response